# Total in nested array Vue

Tags: vue.js, multidimensional-array, count, vue-cli

I'm using vue-cli and I'm trying to figure out how I can get the total numbers of active in Tasks array.

```
Tasks: [ 
            {name: 'Sam',  available: [{active: 'yes', day:'Mon'},{active: 'yes', day:'Tues'}]},
            {name: 'Yoko', available: [{active: 'yes', day:'Mon'}]},
            {name: 'Alec', available: [{active: 'yes', day:'Wed'},{active: 'yes', day:'Thurs'}]},
            {name: 'Pat',  available: [{active: 'yes', day:'Tues'},{active: 'yes', day:'Thurs'} ]}
       ]
 
Expected output:
Total: 7
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need iterate through tasks array, filter active items and sum it with reduce method:

```js
const tasks = [ 
  {name: 'Sam',  available: [{active: 'yes', day:'Mon'},{active: 'yes', day:'Tues'}]},
  {name: 'Yoko', available: [{active: 'yes', day:'Mon'}]},
  {name: 'Alec', available: [{active: 'yes', day:'Wed'},{active: 'yes', day:'Thurs'}]},
  {name: 'Pat',  available: [{active: 'yes', day:'Tues'},{active: 'yes', day:'Thurs'} ]}
];

const total = tasks.reduce((sum, task) => {
    return sum + (task.available.filter(item => item.active === 'yes')).length
}, 0)
```